# How to make a number of balls bounce?

Tags: arraylist, bounce

I need to change the "bounce" method in the BallDemo class to allow a user to choose how many bouncing balls there are through a parameter. I need to use a collection to store the balls, and the balls should be placed in a row along the top of the default canvas. Also, the balls should erase when the last ball reaches the end of the canvas. I know I need to use an array list and a for loop for the draw, move, and erase methods but other than that I'm stuck. This is what I have so far:

```
/**
* Simulates a chosen number of specific balls bouncing.
*/
public void bounce(int amount)
{
int ground = 400;   // position of the ground line

myCanvas.setVisible(true);

// draw the ground
myCanvas.drawLine(50, ground, 550, ground);

***ArrayList<BouncingBall> balls = new ArrayList<BouncingBall>();
for(int index; index < amount; index++)
{
  BouncingBall ball = new BouncingBall(0, 0,*** 

// make them bounce
boolean finished =  false;
while(!finished)
{
  myCanvas.wait(50);           // small delay
  ball.move();
  ball2.move();
  // stop once ball has travelled a certain distance on x axis
  if(ball.getXPosition() >= 550 && ball2.getXPosition() >= 550)
    finished = true;
}
ball.erase();
ball2.erase();
}
}
```

The program right now is set to make two balls bounce because it didn't have a parameter at first, it was programmed to make two bouncing balls. The lines with the ArrayList and for loop are what I added but I'm stuck on there. Also, the default canvas has a width of 600 and a height of 500.